# Bind the width and height of a viewport

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I need to bind to the width and height property of the viewport. I tried this:

```
Viewport="15,15,binding Path=Width ElementName=LayerNormalThumb,binding Path=HeightElementName=LayerNormalThumb"
```

Binding like this has worked for me if I there is only one property, ex Source="{binding ...}".

I also tried this:

```
<VisualBrush.Viewport>
   <Rect X="15" Y="15" Width="{Binding ElementName=LayerNormalThumbnail, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=LayerNormalThumbnail, Path=Height}"/>
</VisualBrush.Viewport>
```

which I thought would work but im getting

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Height' property of type 'Rect'. A
>   'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a
>   DependencyObject.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360381/set-a-margin-from-a-binding. You may need to use IMultiValueConverter instead of IValueConverter though (depends on how you want to pass width and height into the converter).