# Using Xaml in MVVM arc. how to set Padding of button property element syntax

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

I need to set padding of button dynamically using binding.I need to change position of button on Click.

I need something like this

```
 <Button.Padding Left="{Binding Alpha}"
                   Top="{Binding Beta}"
                   Right="{Binding Delta}"
                   Bottom="{Binding Gamma}" />
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: similar to how it's done with [Margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360381/set-a-margin-from-a-binding)

Comment: however, if you want to change the position, are you sure that you don't want to change the Margin? The padding changes the position of the buttons content, not the button itself.

Comment: @Default yeah i meant Margin but when i use Margin="{Binding Padding},0,0,0" i got  exception  *Expression must end with '}'*

Comment: You have to bind the whole expression. The system cannot convert `{Binding Padding}` to a number. You can check the linked question for different solutions of solving your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Solved using your ref.

Answer (score 0):

The `Padding` property is a `Thickness`, which can be declared in XAML like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Padding>
        <Thickness Left="..."
                   Top="..."
                   Right="..."
                   Bottom="..."/>
    </Button.Padding>
</Button>
```

Also, I believe that @Default is right, you are probably after `Margin`, not `Padding`. If this is correct, simply change `Button.Padding` in the code I provided above to `Button.Margin`.

Comment: I got Exception using that  "Cannot assign property "Left": type mismatch between "Xamarin.Forms.Binding" and "System.Double""